# Randomly Element Color Change in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the children color of `<h1></h1>` child continuously after 1 second. I have written the code in React but it is not working properly. Here is the given code:

```
var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

function App(){
    var [ctime, updateTime] = useState(time);
    var [color, setColor] = useState('#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));

    var updatedTime = () => {
        time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
        updateTime(time);
        setColor(color);
    }


    setInterval(updatedTime,1000);
    return(
        <h1 style = {{textAlign: 'center', color : `${color}`}}>{ctime}</h1>
      );
}
```

I have returned from app function a `<h1></h1>` jsx tag like this:

```
return(
      <h1 style = {{textAlign: 'center', color : `${color}`}}>{ctime}</h1>
    );
```

Here `ctime` is working properly but `color` is working but not properly.
For first 2 or 3 seconds, the `color` changes perfectly but after that the changing rate of `color` increases exponentially.

Any Solution, please?

Comment: I believe that you should put the `setInterval` inside a `useEffect`..

Comment: yes, it is working now...
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using useEffect to only call setInterval one time.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  var [ctime, updateTime] = useState();
  var [color, setColor] = useState(
    "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
  );

  var updatedTime = () => {
    const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    const ccolor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    updateTime(time);
    setColor(ccolor);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const inter = setInterval(updatedTime, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(inter);
    };
  }, []);

  return <h1 style = {{textAlign: 'center', color : color}}>{ctime}</h1>;
}
```

live: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-blackburn-k11dj?file=/src/App.js:0-656